# How to assign the angular factory method dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Actually my requirement is to assign the angular factory method dynamically.

Please have a look this code:

```
angular.forEach(scope.mapperData.collections.controltype.rowset, function (value, index) {
    if (value.controltypeid == scope.controlId){
        scope.controlData = value.controltypename;
        controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory[scope.controlData]());
        $compile(controlContent)(scope);
        element.append(controlContent);
    }
}); 

var controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory[scope.controlData]());
```

In the above code has `scope.controlData`. The value will come dynamically. I need to assign the like

```
var controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory[ThirdPartyAutoComplete]());
```

Or

```
var controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory.ThirdPartyAutoComplete());
```

layoutControlsFactory Code

```
bosAppModule.factory("layoutControlsFactory",function($compile){
    var layoutControlsFactory={};

    layoutControlsFactory.ThirdPartyAutoComplete=function(controlId){
        console.log("## Create ThirdPartyAutoComplete");
        var template='<input kendo-auto-complete>';
        return template;
    };


    return layoutControlsFactory;
});
```

I tried but it's showing error.

> typeError: layoutControlsFactory[scope.controlData] is not a function

I think I explained my requirement well. Please let me know if you need more details. Can any one help me to achieve this?

Comment: what does `layoutControlsFactory` look like and what is the value of `scope.controlData`? If they have appropriate data, your syntax would work [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jyonvcj4/)

Comment: @Jamiec - Now i added layoutControlsFactory code. Please have look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using square bracket notation, the bit in square brackets needs to be a string

```
var controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory[ThirdPartyAutoComplete]());
```

should be

```
var controlContent = angular.element(layoutControlsFactory["ThirdPartyAutoComplete"]());
```

A mockup example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/jyonvcj4/1/